# how to read and write objects from/in binary file in c++ correctly

Tags: c++, file, object

Below is the basic structure code for my super market billing and stock editing program
class:

```
class Admin
{
public:
     admin();
private:
     int Pid;
     char name[20];
     double quant;
     double price;
     double disc;
     double net_price;

     friend istream &read(istream&, Admin&);
     friend ostream &show(ostream&, const Admin);
};

istream &read(istream&, Admin&);
ostream &show(ostream&, const Admin);
```

definition of friend functions:

```
istream &read(istream &is, Admin &commodity)
{
    double dis;

    fflush(stdin);
    is>>commodity.Pid;

    is.getline(commodity.name,30);

    is>>commodity.quant
      >>commodity.price
      >>commodity.disc;

    dis=grs_pr*(commodity.disc/100);

    commodity.net_price=grs_pr-dis;

    return is;
}

ostream &show(ostream &os, const Admin thing)
{
    os << thing.name <<"   " << thing.quant <<"   "
       << thing.price <<"   " << thing.disc <<"   "
       << thing.net_price << endl;

    return os;
}
```

Main function:

```
int main()
{
    admin item;

    while(read(cin,item)
    {
        ofstream file;
        file.open("Stock.dat",ios::binary | ios::app);
        file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&item),sizeof(Admin));
    }
    ifstream readFile("Stock.dat",ios::in|ios::binary);

    while(!readFile.eof())
    {
        readFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*> (&item),sizeof(Admin));
        Admin readedItem;
        read(readFile,readedItem);    /*i have used read and show function to watch the values that are read by readFile but every time show function output some five exponential values like 5.23689e-301*/
        show(cout,readedItem);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Please tell me what is wrong in above code and what should i do to correct it,
my motive is to read from the file created and to alter or edit the data of the item that is to be selected by mentioning the product ID by the user, please help me how to attain this functionality.

Comment: What *specific* problem you are facing?

Comment: @n.m.my problem is that i am not able to read the data (objects) from the file

Comment: "I am not able to do this or that" is not specific. "I am getting this error (paste the text of the error)" is. "I expect the program to print FOO but it prints BAR" is.

Comment: One problem is that the code you've shown won't compile.  For example, in `main()`, you have `while(read(cin,item)
 {`.  This is simply wrong, missing a parenthesis.  Your code should be an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  Amongst other things, that means it should compile!

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't implement a naiive serialization yourself. Use a library.

See i.e. answers [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18208129/847349), [2+comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18186809/847349), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17277321/847349), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17269736/847349)

Also, don't put logic of data manipulation (i.e. `commodity.net_price=grs_pr-dis;`) in your data serialization

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding right then your read and show loop should be

```
    for (;;)
    {
        readFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*> (&item),sizeof(Admin));
        if (readFile.eof())
            break;
        show(cout,item);
    }
```

For some reason you were reading twice, first into a variable called `item` and then into another variable called `readItem`. You only need to read once. Also `while (!readFile.eof())` is wrong because you must test for end of file **after** you read not **before**.