# Writing some data structure to file

Tags: c++

Imagine I have an object of class `Product`, which has member variables like: `price, name, etc.`.
And say I have 10 such Product objects.
Now I want to write all 10 of them say to some file `Products.dat`.
Later I want to say retrieve 6th product from file.
How is it achieved usually in C++? (I am merely interested
in retrieving part).

Comment: `fseek(fp, record_size * 5, SEEK_SET);`

Comment: Look at the xml or yaml fileformats.

Comment: @DevZer0: And writing would be smth like `fd.write(productRecord, sizeof(Product))` - right? (after correct seek)

Comment: yes but take care of the endianness if you move the dat file to an other computer

Comment: @user2380470 not just a new computer but different CPU architecture completely

Comment: if you want to read the 6th, it would be `fd.read()`

Comment: "And writing would be smth like `fd.write(productRecord, sizeof(Product))`, right?" - this approach only has a chance of working if Product embeds all simple "POD" data... any pointers, references, strings etc. won't be written or read properly.

Comment: consider using a NoSQL database, such as [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) or [Protocol Buffers](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) together with any other NoSQL database

Answer (score 2):

How you retrieve your set of data depends, on how you store the data. If you have a fixed size structure, you can use `fseek(file, dataSize * RecordNr, SEEK_SET);` to position the file at the intended offset, and then read the data from there.
This would require that, for exmaple your strings like `name` have a fixed maximum length and the record always is stored with that known length.

If your data structure is of variable length, then you would have either to calculate the length of each record, or you must read them individually. In this case, a better alternative might be to use some existing library like sqlite or XML to manage your file content.

Another alternative for variable length structures is, to maintain a second file as an index, where you store the offsets of each record.

If you need only this small number of records for some assignment using fseek with a fixed length record is probably enough.

**Update**

In order to use a fixed size record, you should create your data structure without any pointers. Otherwise you would have to read/write those members individually.

For eaxmple:

```
class Product
{
    double Price;
    int Category;
    char Name[50];
    char ArticleId[10];
};
```

Instead of

```
class Product
{
    double Price;
    int Category;
    char *Name;
    char *ArticleId;
};
```

You should be aware though, that such a fixed structure, makes your program only work on the platform you wrote it. You can't easily copy the data files to other platforms. If you intend to have compatbility with other platforms you should not use this approach, as it makes porting much harder.

Comment: Hi Devolous thanks. Say my data structure is of fixed length. I also like the approach with `fseek(file, dataSize * RecordNr, SEEK_SET);` just I heard in such case my class `Product` must be a POD for example right? e.g., for me to be able to do `fd.write(record,sizeof(Product))` - isn't it?

Comment: See my update in the answer, and yes, it would be  POD (had to google what this means). :)

Comment: Hi, what you mean with 'platform' I may need to write it for some embedded device; but I like this approach

Comment: I mean, that if you i.e. code this on Windows and then want to run it on a HP-UX machine, it will not work if you copy the data file over and try to read it. The data you write this way on one machine only works on another machine if the memory layout is the same as on the other machine, so this kind of writing data is kind of hardwired to the binary of your executable. It may not even work properly with a different compiler on the same machine.

Comment: hm.. I see but I think my app will run always on similar embedded device. Otherwise, alternative is Tony D's suggestion I believe. But I think for me this solution will work too

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you start by having a file format such as:

```
39.28
product name
other data
47.12
another product name
other data
...
```

You can then read through the file using an `ifstream` object, getting textual lines one at a time using `getline()`, and numeric values using `operator>>` to a numeric value (but be careful to ignore the rest of the line so the next `getline` doesn't read an empty line).  Keep track of which field and record you're reading until you reach the desired record.

If you need faster access, you need to use fixed-width fields which requires a lot more knowledge of output formatting... best to learn that as a second step.  With fixed-width fields you can use the seek function on ifstream to jump directly to the relevant data, then start reading using `getline` or `operator>>` as above, or even `ifstream::read()`.

EDIT: making the example more explicit - and adding a product_index field - as per the comments.  This might need a bit of debugging/tweaking, but the basic idea's hopefully useful...

```
struct Product
{
    double price_;
    double product_index_;
    std::string product_name_;
    std::string other_data_;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Product& p)
    {
        return os << p.price_ << '\n'
                  << p.product_index_ << '\n'
                  << p.product_name_ << '\n'
                  << p.other_data << '\n';
    }

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::ostream& is, Product& p)
    {
        is >> p.price_ >> p.product_index_;
        is.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        getline(is, p.product_name_);
        getline(p.other_data);
        return is;
    }
};

    // to read your input file...
    if (ifstream input("input.dat"))
    {
        Product p;
        while (input >> p)
            do_something_with(p);

        if (!input.eof())
            std::cerr << "error during parsing of input file\n";
    }
    else
        std::cerr << "error opening input file\n";
```

Comment: thanks I will give thought to this answer too. ps. I liked the approach with `fd.write(record,sizeof(Product))` - just I know then Product must be a POD right? Although I have seen implementations where `Product` class would even contain a `std::string` object.

Comment: If you use pointers or other complex data types, like std::string you must de-/serilize your data. essentially this means, that you write functions that know how to save and restore the data structures. But then you can't simply use read/write operations directly to memory, as you need the transalation. The example of TonyD is such an approach, because here you have to parse the file individually.

Comment: Ok, got it, I won't use any complex data types, like std::string for isntance etc.

Comment: @pseudonym_127: some std::string implementations may have what's known as the short string optimisation (SSO), where values of only a few characters are embedded directly into the string object, but often (and always for longer strings) the memory's dynamically allocated (i.e. by default on the heap). A simple binary `read`/`write` of the `std::string` object itself *may* "work" for empty and/or SSO strings, but never for heap-allocated strings. Separately, if using this binary block approach, be careful to read back into properly aligned memory - if you don't know what that means just ask.

Comment: @TonyD: Thanks. I checked now and made mistake now std::Strings were not written using the suggestion by Devolous. As I got if I want to use Devolous approach I must keep in mind PODS. Also as i said in other posts my app may run on one type of embedded device. I am interested in your suggestion too, just I am not yet well familiar with writing using `ifstreams` - so I'd have to check that. Would I for instance store product index below numbers `39.28` which you mentioned and that way deduce product index right?

Comment: @pseudonym_127: are the product indices just increasing record numbers, or are they something else?  If you want an extra field you can just add it in.  I've added some code above to give a bit more colour on how to do all this, both for input and output.  Should get you started anyway, then you can debug and sort it all out.

Comment: @TonyD: I will study your sample, though it's not compiling yet:) Anyway do  you have some links which explain your approach in more details? And you say this approach does not have portability issues right?

Comment: I don't have any particular links.  The individual methods can be found by googling "istream ignore", "istream getline" etc..  This is portable, yes.  If you want fixed length output, you probably want to check the `<iomanip>` header and `std::width` (google "ostream io manipulators").  There will be quite a lot of questions and example code scattered around SO though.

Comment: @Tony D: I think your method is referred as serialization right? Aren't there some general links on that topic for c++? That is what I asked. Not links related to your particular solution of course :) I just want to know what are the ways to do it in C++, I know boost is one way too.

Comment: @Tony D: You may want to look at my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277070/doing-serialization-using-streams-c

Comment: @pseudonym_127: yes, "serialisation" or "externalisation" or "streaming".  Glad to see James helped you fix up my broken implementation! ;-)

Comment: @Tony D: I actually fixed big part of it myself :))

Comment: @pseudonym_127: great - guess you understand it well enough to use it in future.  Creating those operators can be very useful in lots of programs, as you can use them to send the object representation to e.g. `std::cout` or `std::ostringstream` too, displaying it to the user or in a log file.

Comment: Thanks Tony D, I also hope I will be able to use it in future. I still asked some question to James though. And benefit of that approach as compared to Devolous approach (although I like that one too) is no limitation to PODs and portability right as I understood?

Comment: @pseudonym_127: that's right... whatever fields you can find a way to serialise that you can read back happily will work, but sometimes it can be tricky: for example, if some of your strings contained newline characters inside them, then the code above would obviously break as `getline()` expects one string per line.  If that was a scenario you cared about, you'd need to escape newlines using some notation of your choice (e.g.putting \n for a newline, then \\ for a single \, just like string literals in your program)... you could create two functions for conversion to/from that convention.

Comment: @Tony D: no, it was about `wstring` so far ..maybe you could also have a look at it in the mean time ..

Comment: @Tony D: This approach seems to have an issue if, in class Product, I want to have one string of type `string` and another of type `wstring`?

Comment: @pseudonym_127: I'm afraid I very rarely use any wide character functions... best to ask a separate question and get help from someone who's familiar with the issues.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

consider using a NoSQL database, such as [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) or [Protocol Buffers](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) together with any other NoSQL database, if you are serious about your task and care about performance, portability and binary compatibility.

Opening the connection to the database, which is running in a separate process:

```
mongo::DBClientConnection c;
c.connect("localhost");
```

Querying the database would look like that:

```
std::unique_ptr<DBClientCursor> cursor =
     c.query("mystore.products", BSONObj());
while (cursor->more()) {
     BSONObj p = cursor->next();
     std::cout << p.getStringField("name") << std::endl;
```

Along the lines of ["Getting Started with the C++ Driver"](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-cpp-driver/)

And inserting the objects into the database:

```
BSONObj p = BSON( "name" << "A nice book" << "price" << 42 );
c.insert("mystore.products", p);
```

Update, more: if you just need serialization, but no efficient querying, transactions, etc, etc, you "merely" need a good serialization strategy: [JSON](https://github.com/jbenet/bson-cpp), [BSON](https://github.com/jbenet/bson-cpp), [Protocol Buffers](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/), [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/) or [XML](http://pugixml.org/), [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) or [cpgf](http://www.cpgf.org/document/serialization-save-load.html) might help