# Doing serialization using streams C++

Tags: c++

I implemented some serialization / deserialization using C++ after some help on this forum.
The file seems to be written correctly but when I read it, new lines are ignored and some data is printed along each other, like this:

[image]

This is my code. Any feedback, help, how to improve correct it, greatly appreciated:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>      // std::ifstream
using namespace std;

struct Product
{
    double price_;
    double product_index_;
    std::string product_name_;
    std::string other_data_;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Product& p)
    {
        return os << p.price_ << '\n'
                  << p.product_index_ << '\n'
                  << p.product_name_ << '\n'
                  << p.other_data_ << '\n';
    }

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Product& p)
    {
        is >> p.price_ >> p.product_index_;
        is.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

        getline(is,p.product_name_);
        getline(is,p.other_data_);

        return is;
    }
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Product s1,s2,s3,s4;

    s1.price_ = 100;
    s1.product_index_ = 0;
    s1.product_name_= "flex";
    s1.other_data_ = "dat001";

    s2.price_ = 200;
    s2.product_index_ = 1;
    s2.product_name_= "brr";
    s2.other_data_ = "dat002";

    s3.price_ = 300;
    s3.product_index_ = 2;
    s3.product_name_= "megatex";
    s3.other_data_ = "dat003";

    // write
    fstream file1("c:\\test.dat",ios::out|ios::binary|ios::app);
    file1_file << s1 << s2 << s3;
    file1_file.close();

    // read
    ifstream file2("c:\\test.dat");

    Product p;
    while (file2 >> p)
    {
            cout<<p.price_<<endl;
            cout<<p.product_index_<<endl;
            cout<<p.product_name_;
            cout<<p.other_data_;
    }

    if (!file2.good())
         std::cerr << "error during parsing of input file\n";
    else
        std::cerr << "error opening input file\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Also, why do I get the error in the end?

PS. What is the benefit of above approach as compared to approach using read and writes, like: `write(record, sizeof(Product))` and `seek(record_size * n, SEEK_SET)`, `read(record, sizeof(Product))` (reading n-th product); hint: I've heard POD related limitations and portability

Comment: Unless for some reason you're not allowed to use boost, you should take a look at boost.serialization. Will spare you a lot of inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

Today you almost never need to implement your own low-level serialization.

Try [JSON](https://github.com/kazuho/picojson), [BSON](https://github.com/jbenet/bson-cpp), [Protocol Buffers](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/), [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/) or [XML](http://pugixml.org/).

There are [quite a lot](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) of [libraries](http://www.cpgf.org/document/serialization-save-load.html), that will do it better than "roll-your-own"...

You intended to write a binary serialization, but you insert  EOL ('\n') characters. That's not a good choice of dividing a binary stream into tokens.

Comment: Where do you see any binary serialization?

Comment: upvoted. I have to struggle with a real badly done serialization from an university project we took the code base over. If its not for "understanding" please try to avoid writing your own serializer...

Comment: @JamesKanze: I don't see one, but I see `fstream file1("c:\\test.dat",ios::out|ios::binary|ios::app);` in the pasted code

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov Which means a text file using the binary conventions for line endings and end of file.

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov Or are you supposing that the OP _thinks_ he's doing binary serialization, because he specified `ios::binary`?  (A lot of people unfamiliar with iostream do suppose this.)

Comment: @JamesKanze, that's what I was hoping to convey :)

Comment: @Dmitry, do you mean I have a mistake in code? by referrnig to `but you insert EOL ('\n') characters`??

Comment: @pseudonym_127, one can't say, you have a mistake there. Just that if you do so, it will be perhaps harder to parse and not flexible. If you want your software to be extendable, you'll need some version-safe serialization format, for which I would recommend using any library I mentioned. Since I see, you want to serialize unicode, the task will be even more complicated without some help

Comment: I'll look at those libraries a bit later, just wanted to check this way first

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error message is clear: you input from
`binary_file2` until an input fails (generally because there is
no more data, because you've reached end of file), then you say
to output "error parsing of input file" if any input has failed.

As for the loss of new lines, you read `product_name_` and
`other_data_` using `std::getline`, which extracts throught the
final newline, but does *not* insert it into the string it is
reading.  In the loop where you're outputting to `cout`, you
need an `endl` after each field.

With regards to your question: the main advantage of doing it
the way you are, instead of using `write(record,
sizeof(Product))`, etc., is that it works.  Generally speaking,
you cannot write binary images of what you have in memory, and
expect to be able to reread them correctly.  If you want to be
able to seek (which can be useful), you'll have to define
a fixed length representation in your output file.  (This can be
done by forcing each output field to have a fixed length, using
`std::setw`.)

Comment: Hey, I corrected some stuff also as you mentioned in my code, and it works now. So I should remove  `!file2.good()` ?? check? ps. So what I wrote above, is an OK way to store data and read on disk? Thanks.

Comment: @pseudonym_127 Replace the `!file2.good()` with `!file2.eof()`: if your input fails for any reason other than `eof`, it's a corrupt file.  And this is a perfectly good way to store very simple data on disk.  (For more complex data, where fields may be absent, or strings contain new lines, you'll need something more complex.)

Comment: James, just one more thing, how would I be able to adapt this example if I had `wstring` instead of `string` in my Products class for example? Thanks.

Comment: @pseudonym_127 It depends.  If you output it to a `wofstream`, and input using a `wifstream`, it should just work.  If you want to be able to read the file from a wide variety of machines, however, you'll probably want to translate the contents of the strings to UTF-8, using some of the code conversion libraries out there.  (Depending on the platform, `wstring` could be UTF-16 (Windows, AIX), UTF-32 (Linux) or something else completely.

Comment: Hi James, ok, I don't have compiler now, I'll check with wifstream etc. tomorrow. Also, what happens if one string is std:String and other std: wstring? ps. I'm not sure I understood what you meant in the end with encodings, the way I envisioned handling unicodes in c++ is using wstring when needed, with L"" strings and wscpy etc. functions... I think that assumes UCS-2 unicode...

Comment: Now, I get this error in the `<< operator` that: `"Error 1 error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>' to 'std::wofstream &'" ` if I want to use wstring :( ? any help?

Comment: @pseudonym_127 I don't think you can mix the two strings.  If you have `std::string`, you have to use `std::istream` and `std::ostream`; if you have `std::wstream`, you have to use `std::wistream` and `std::wostream`.  If you have both, you have to convert one to the other; how you do this depends on the encoding you have or want in the two streams.  The standard has `std::codecvt` to do this, but this will only work if you have the appropriate locales.  Otherwise, there is `iconv`.  The problem with both is that they don't support `std::string`, only `char*`.

Comment: Hmm.. that's a bit of a problem, it might be the likely case that a class has one `string` and one `wstring` member right? does using char *, wchar_t * instead of string, wstrings, help in this case?

Comment: @pseudonym_127 With regards to UCS-2: all of the platforms I know claim to support UCS-4.  It is the encoding format which varies: for narrow char, it will be UTF-8, for wide char, either UTF-16 or UTF-32.  (Windows and AIX, for example, use UTF-16 to represent the code points in USC-4.  This means that they handle surrogates correctly.)  If you actually have to manipulate the data, you might want to look into the ICU library.  Otherwise, I'd just use UTF-8 and `char` everywhere.  (But where do your strings come from?  That might determine the encoding.)

Comment: Using `char*` and `wchar_t*` should help if you are outputting to a `std::wostream`; both are defined.  Reading is more complicated, because there isn't a form of `getline` for both, only  `>>` (which reads "words", not lines).

Comment: >>`" Otherwise, I'd just use UTF-8 and char everywhere"`
Would that solve Unicode problem and let me write say in Russian using my program etc?

Comment: @pseudonym_127 Probably.  You still have to get your Unicode into UTF-8 format, but maybe you can get it in that format from the start.

Comment: Maybe I can get the strings in UTF8 from start don't know. But anyway, and sorry for disturbing you, just I am lost a bit. In my situation (given I want one wstring and one string say) what is the best way I should proceed, you recommend?

Comment: @pseudonym_127 It's hard to say without knowing more about the application; there are no universal solutions.  But from the little you've shown, I would probably only use `std::string`, putting UTF-8 into it when I wanted Unicode.

Comment: Hey James, I thought UTF8 was for Unicode -- and `string` does not support Unicode right? (that is why wchar was invented) - how come I can use `string` and UTF8 together, could you explain, thanks?

Comment: @pseudonym_127 `string` doesn't support anything related to the encoding.  It's just a sequence of `char`; you can put Latin-1, UTF-8 or even just small integers in it, and it doesn't care.

Comment: I see. But why did they invent `wchar_t` then if I can put everything, for example UTF 8, inside `string` and thus in char-s?

Comment: @pseudonym_127 First, `wchar_t` goes back to before universal Unicode.  But most importantly, the _idea_ behind `wchar_t` was that to support more than 256 characters without requiring multibyte encodings.  If you're doing complex text manipulations, it may be significantly simpler if you don't have to deal with a single code point spread out over multiple units.  Similarly, Windows and AIX adopted UTF-16 before surrogate code points where invented, when Unicode had less than 65000 characters.