# C++ Read and write multiple objects of same class

Tags: c++, object, readfile

```
airport air(1,2,3); //an airport constructor
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("rishab",ios::app||ios::binary);
myfile.write((char*)air,sizeof(airport);
myfile.close();
```

Such commands are called multiple times in my program to get info of many airports. Basically the binary file is full of airports.
I need to read all these airports into an array later on. How do I read the file so that I get the array of airports.

Apologies if this question is too basic. I am in high school learning about pointers and shortest path graphs.

Comment: That depends on the definition of the `airport` class.

Comment: class airport {
int planeCapacity;
int acceptPlanesFrom;
//and a few other ints
public:
constructor..
accessor methods
};
Thats it.

Comment: I do not know what makes people think that your input file contains valid binary dumps of objects. You did not say that. The way most of answers make this IMO risky assumption. Also they present approach that was somewhat valid and used in `c` but is obsolete. If you are in `c++` and dealing with objects it will end up very badly sooner than later. Smallest change in `airport` will break the compatibility. Can you tell how is the input file created? You cannot really design reading method with out knowing the storing one. They are strongly coupled. Also definition of `airport` would be useful.

Comment: `ios::app||ios::binary` is the logical or so the result of this is 0 or 1. You want the bitwise or `ios::app|ios::binary`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do is serialization. This way of serializing objects is not stable, and highly depends on what airport is. It's better to use explicit serialization.

[Here](http://wiki.msgpack.org/display/MSGPACK/Design+of+Serialization)'s a description of what serialization is and why is it made this way.

In [MessagePack](http://wiki.msgpack.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1081387) a typical serialization-deserialization scenario would look like this:

```
struct airport {
 std::string name; //you can name your airports here
 int planeCapacity;
 int acceptPlanesFrom;
 MSGPACK_DEFINE(name,planeCapacity,acceptPlanesFrom);
};
```

...

```
// define your airports
std::vector<airport> airports;
airport a={"BLA",1,2};
airport b={"BLB",3,4};
airports.push_back(a);
airports.push_back(b);

// create a platform-independent byte sequence from your data
msgpack::sbuffer sbuf;
msgpack::pack(sbuf, airports) ;
std::string data=sbuf.data();//you can write that into a file

msgpack::unpacked msg;
// get your data safely back
msgpack::unpack(&msg, sbuf.data(), sbuf.size());
msgpack::object obj = msg.get();

std::cout<<obj<<std::endl;

// now convert the bytes back to your objects
std::vector<airport> read_airports;
obj.convert(&read_airports);
std::cout<<read_airports.size()<<std::endl;
```

with the console output:

```
[["BLA", 1, 2], ["BLB", 3, 4]]
2
```

- [some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17277321/847349) [more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17269736/847349)

Answer (score 5):

Well, if you're sure that your file is valid, then you can simply use `read()` until you reach EOF.
Each `read()` - of `sizeof(airport)`- will give you a valid `airport` object.

Note that storing the binary "value" of and object will result in an invalid object when loading it if it contains pointers - or references.

EDIT: `myfile.write((char*)&air,sizeof(airport);` will write the content of the `air` object the file. By doing this, you're actually writing the object, not the pointer.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your answer. I now understand that I am writing pointers to the file and trying to read the object. Can you explain me how to write the object on the file and not the pointer.

Comment: what you need is structured serialization of data, not of the c++ memory constructs.

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov Yeah exactly, except when your class contains only  basic types (or of objects which themself are of basic types).

Comment: @Xaqq it is therefore perhaps of advantage to separate data and actions upon it. There's surely much more to serialization than just "how to do it". In a simple case like thie one sketched a file dump would suffice, but most probably, that won't be good enough. For example, data should be designed, i.e. to avoid multiple serialization of the same objects and circular references.

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov I totally agree with you, but in this case it looks like the OP question is about a rather simple form of serialization -- looks like a introduction exercise to serialization.

Answer (score 0):

```
ofstream myfile;

std::vector<airport> vec;
myfile.open("rishab",ios::app||ios::binary);
while(myfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&air),sizeof(airport)) != 0)
   vec.push_back(air);

myfile.close();
```

Now use `vec` for processing

Comment: should be `(char *)&air`.

Comment: Will this work since I am sending a pointer to the file and not an object?
Sorry just getting mixed up. And now I'll have to iterrate through the  vector right?

Answer (score 0):

You can program it like this.

```
struct AirPort
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
int main()
{
    std::vector<AirPort> airportList;
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename,"rb");
    if( NULL != fp)
    {
        while(!feof(fp))
        {
            AirPort ap;
            if (fread(&ap,sizeof(ap),1,fp)==1)
            {
                airportList.push_back(ap);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you. However, I am confused a bit since I havent done much of vectors and lists. However, Airport is a class and from my understanding now, I am writing a pointer value and trying to read the object which will obviously be insignificant.
Could you help me with my issue?

Comment: You means how to program if not use vectors or lists? I'm not understand clear.My English is not very good.Can you speak exactly what you want. It's better put your c++ code here.